# Dojo Framework Application with Windows Authentication

Tags: javascript, dojo, iis-7.5

I'm trying to develop a web application using the JS DOJO Framework libraries, I don't really have a problem there, the thing is that it is required that the web application uses windows authentication for the users to log in, and some parts or sections (dojo controls and menus) of the developed application should be available in function of the user role.

I would like to know what is the best strategy to authenticate the user?, and what is the best way in the JS side to get and validate the user roles and info of the current user to change the UI?.

I will vbe be using IIS 7.5

Answer (score 0):

On the pure JS side of thing this should not be possible as granting the browser that kind of information is a security threat.

If you estrictly need a windows authentication, your best bet would be something like a plugin  for the browser(IE) or flash(not sure about this one).

basiclally your plugin would request the user credentials from the client and pass that on to JS and submit it to your server, after that just keep the credentials in server sesion.